# Jquery downloading

Tags: jquery

when I tried to download jquery from jquery.com by clicking on the download link, the file opened in the browser (see image below) but didn't download.

I'm a very newbie at all this, so I'm not 100% sure this is not what's supposed to happen, but I think there's a problem. Can anyone explain?

[image: image of download]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Ctrl + s the page to a .js file on your machine
- Select all, copy and paste into a new text file
- Load the jQuery script directly into your HTML with

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @jackpot last method does not applicable if user is testing something on localhost without internet or took too much time to load if net speed is slow..

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem. Just copy the text and save it in your local with .js extension and start using it. That will be your jQuery copy.

Answer (score 2):

simply save(CTRL+S) this page on your desktop..and u have **latest jQuery code** in your hand  :)

Comment: is that how it's supposed to work or is this just a workaround? I'm used to a file actually downloading..thanks.

Comment: @Michael i also face same problem when i put my first foot into jQuery world